# Can't get encrypted storage React native

Tags: react-native

I have React native app that store encrypted storage. But when i wanna get value from Encrypted Storage it return `{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}`. Is something wrong? i'm using [react-native-encrypted-storage](https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage)

This my code when getting value from  Encrypted Storage

```js
export async function getToken() {
  try {
    return await EncryptedStorage.getItem('token');
 
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem today with asyncStorage, but solution may apply to your problem.

Try this:

```
return await EncryptedStorage.getItem('token').then((response) => {return response});
```